# Google Drive API v3 - UserInfo endpoint url

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I've started writing Google Drive adapter using Google.Apis.Drive.v3 library. So far I was able to figure out:

- login URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
- access token URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

I am looking for:

- user info endpoint URL: http:// ??????

I've searched it in the API documentation but I cannot find it there. Am I missing something?

Please accept my sincere apologies if this is duplicated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end point for each of the methods can be found of the top of the page for that method in the documentation

[About.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/about/get)

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about

Once you have your access token remember to add Access_token= to the request.

Top tip: find a client library in your chosen language will make it easier.